# How to remove value in nested Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object:

```
objectData = { 
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2', 
  key3: { nestedKey1: 'nestedValue1', nestedKey2: 'nestedValue2'}
};
```

I want to make a new object without key1 and **nestedKey1.**

I know how to remove "key1". **But how can I remove "nestedKey1"?**

Here my code, where I remove key 1

```
let myObject = { ...objectData };

      const { key1, ...newObject } = myObject;
```

newObject will contain :

```
objectData = {  
  key2: 'value2', 
  key3: { nestedKey1: 'nestedValue1', nestedKey2: 'nestedValue2'}
};
```

Comment: Is `objectData` state? (if so, the current answers proposing `delete` will modify your state in place, which can cause rendering bugs in React)

Comment: `const { key1, key3: { nestedKey1, ...rest2 }, ...rest } = myObject` and `const newObject = { ...rest, key3: rest2 }`

Comment: Yes Nick Parsons, it is. Actually trying your answer, thanks

Comment: Actually working with Adiga answer, thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

```js
delete myObject.key1
delete myObject.key3.nestedKey1
```

Answer (score 0):

there is `delete` keyword in JS

`delete objectData.key3.nestedKey1`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Wow, amazing! thanks. I got "Cannot delete property 'nestedKey1' of #<Object>. I'm trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following -

```
delete objectData['key3']['nestedKey1']
```